# Taking the King while (self) being in check in Blitz Chess

Tags: rules, checkmate, check, kings

- In Blitz (5-min Chess) your opponent puts you in check.
- You then make a move that places your opponent in check.

Can your opponent still take your King and claim victory (even though he's in check)?

Comment: This question has been answered several times. Yes, the opponent can claim an illegal move (not necessarily a win though) and no, the opponent cannot take the king.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39499/if-player-a-is-in-check-but-has-a-move-which-will-checkmate-player-b-without-exi?noredirect=1&lq=1